# Logic App ServiceBus trigger error : This messaging entity has already been closed, aborted, or disposed

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-logic-apps

Since yesterday morning, one of our Logic App in charge of reading messages from a ServiceBus Subscription is failing.
The trigger failed with this error : "This messaging entity has already been closed, aborted, or disposed.".
Messages are still in the subscription.

When I use the ServiceBus Explorer to read the subscription (Peek mode), it works fine.
Any ideas?

Comment: I found a way to resolve it: delete the Logic App and recreate it... Unfortunately it is in a production environment and it is not the way I want to manage issues like that.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue however it is intermittent and random happened. Any chance you got the bottom of it please?

Comment: @duongthaiha: unfortunately, the issue disappeared on our side and we don't know what was the root cause...